# How to completely reorganise a table using aggregate data from qualitative information

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a pandas dataframe which has the following layout:

| Column | data type |
| --- | --- |
| 'Water-Binder' | float |
| 'Fly Ash' | float |
| 'Age' | int |
| 'Strength %' | float |

[image: Sample of the dataset]

The age column is qualitative, features records at 1, 3, 7, 14, and 28 days. I want to group the rows by water-binder and fly ash, calculate the mean Strength % for the groups at each age, resulting in a table looking something like this:

| Column | data type |
| --- | --- |
| 'Water-Binder' | float |
| 'Fly Ash' | float |
| 'Mean Strength % 1 day' | float |
| 'Mean Strength % 3 days' | float |
| 'Mean Strength % 7 days' | float |
| 'Mean Strength % 14 days' | float |
| 'Mean Strength % 28 days' | float |

I've been trying to figure out how this could be done. This is the closest thing to something that works that I've managed to achieve:

```
age_strength_model = data[['Water-Binder', 'Fly Ash', 'Age', 'Strength %']].copy()
ages = np.unique(age_strength_model['Age'].values)

# create table investigating the relationship between fly ash, age, and compressive strength
for a in ages:
  age_strength_model.query(f'`Fly Ash` == 0 & Age == {a}').groupby(['Water-Binder'])['Strength %'].transform(lambda x: x.mean())
```

However, that just shows me the values rather than organising them into a dataset and doesn't accommodate for grouping water-binder and fly ash together. How would I achieve the desired end result here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate 'Water-Binder', 'Fly Ash', 'Age' fields and then group:

```
data = [
    [0.43, 0.0, 3, 26.446759],
    [0.43, 0.0, 7, 44.444444],
    [0.43, 0.0, 28, 100.00000],
    [0.43, 0.0, 3, 11.316173],
    [0.43, 0.0, 7, 37.493929]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Water-Binder', 'Fly Ash', 'Age', 'Strength %'])
df['Water-Binder-Fly-Ash-Age'] = (df['Water-Binder'].astype(str)
                                  + '%'
                                  + df['Fly Ash'].astype(str)
                                  + '%'
                                  + df['Age'].astype(str))
df
   Water-Binder  Fly Ash  Age  Strength % Water-Binder-Fly-Ash
0          0.43      0.0    3   26.446759           0.43%0.0%3
1          0.43      0.0    7   44.444444           0.43%0.0%7
2          0.43      0.0   28  100.000000          0.43%0.0%28
3          0.43      0.0    3   11.316173           0.43%0.0%3
4          0.43      0.0    7   37.493929           0.43%0.0%7

# Creates a grouped df with the indices reset and 'Strength %' field renamed.
df_grouped = df.groupby(by='Water-Binder-Fly-Ash-Age').mean()['Strength %'].reset_index()
df_grouped.rename(columns={'Strength %': 'Mean Strength %'}, inplace=True)
df_grouped
  Water-Binder-Fly-Ash-Age  Mean Strength %
0              0.43%0.0%28       100.000000
1               0.43%0.0%3        18.881466
2               0.43%0.0%7        40.969186
```

If you want to recover 'Water-Binder', 'Fly Ash', 'Age' fields, just split it based on the '%' delimiter and 'expand' it:

```
df_grouped[['Water-Binder', 'Fly Ash', 'Age']] = df['Water-Binder-Fly-Ash-Age'].str.split('%', expand=True)
df_grouped
  Water-Binder-Fly-Ash-Age  Mean Strength % Water-Binder  Fly Ash  Age
0              0.43%0.0%28       100.000000         0.43      0.0    3
1               0.43%0.0%3        18.881466         0.43      0.0    7
2               0.43%0.0%7        40.969186         0.43      0.0   28
```